# moderncv: suppress links to last page

Tags: hyperref, moderncv, lastpage

How can I suppress the links to the last page on each page? Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[colorlinks]{moderncv}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\name{}{}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Here we have the page numbering 1/2 and 2/2, but the last 2 is marked red because it is a link. How can I suppress the behavior so that I have 1/2 and 2/2 only?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add something like

```latex
\fancyfoot[r]{\color{color2}\pagenumberfont\strut\thepage/\pageref*{lastpage}}
```

after your `\begin{document}` line. The `*` after the `\pageref` will only print the page number, without a link.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem with documents that consist of a single page. In this case the output is 1/1, but I want the original behavior, i.e. no display of the page number.

Comment: If you want this to be handled automatically, you have to do some `ifthenelse` magic as is done in the [original code](https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/blob/master/moderncv.cls#L146-L151). For the case of only a single page,`\thispagestyle{empty}` is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the original code. How do I have to change it (i.e. what do I have to put in the preamble) so that the situation is handled automatically? Can this in the future maybe be integrated as a `documentclass` option of `moderncv` so that a user can switch between these two behaviors globally?